# I need help on how to find a user inputed word from within a list and then output in what positions the word occors in

Tags: python, list

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence? ")
List1 = sentnce.split(' ')
word = input("What word do you want to find? ")

counter = 0

while index<len(sentence):
    if word in List1[counter]:
```

I just dont kno what else I can change on the code

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `list.index()`:

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence? ")
List1 = sentence.split(' ')
word = input("What word do you want to find? ")

print(List1.index(word))
```

Comment: I have already trie this but it does not work if the word appears more than once in the list

Answer (score 0):

Your code should add exception handling, in case `word` is not found in the list:

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence? ")
List1 = sentence.split()
word = input("What word do you want to find? ")
try:
    print List1.index(word)
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all occurrences of where the word is in the split list use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence? ")
List1 = sentence.split(" ")
word = input("What word do you want to find? ")
print([i for i, w in enumerate(List1) if w == word])
```